# Is there an alien in the area 51 missions in GTA San Andreas?

Tags: grand-theft-auto-san-andreas

I want to know if this is just internet myth or reality; I've read that there are aliens in the underground desert base in San Andreas, that you need night vision to see them, etc., but have never confirmed this.

I've finished San Andreas once and I haven't seen any aliens, but maybe I have missed something?

Comment: IIRC (which is why its not an answer) you go chasing around something that is though to be transporting an alien or some such.. and if you destroy it I think it looked like it was.. but San Andreas was a long time ago :)

Comment: I've played through San Andreas at least six times, but haven't touched it in several years. I don't remember ever seeing an Alien. But, since I'm not 100% about it (it's been too long) I won't post as answer.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I catch the aliens?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/75253/how-do-i-catch-the-aliens)

Answer (score 8):

You will not find any aliens in the Console versions or the vanilla PC version of GTA San Andreas.

Any and all alien videos/claims are done with mods for the PC version.

Answer (score 0):

There are no aliens in GTA San Andreas. The only interesting thing you will find at Area 51 is a jetpack if you walk all the way inside it.

Comment: Instead of posting your own answer with basically the same content, you shuld upvote the other answer which says exactly what you say minus the jetpack (which is not relevant to the question and would better fit as a comment).

Answer (score -2):

Aliens do exist in GTA SA - I've seen them myself next to mount Chiliad or on it, I never used any mods. You can also see them in area 51 if you're lucky. I've also seen them on a console version.