# How do I catch the aliens?

Tags: grand-theft-auto-san-andreas

On GTA:SA I have seen the aliens but I don't have the smallest idea how to catch them or fight them. I tried with a hydra plane but the UFO just disappeared.

Comment: what game is this about?

Comment: Gta san Andreas

Comment: On playstaytion 2

Comment: I think your only possible interaction with the aliens is [dancing](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vb4JMpR9KAM).

Answer (score 3):

There is no way to catch that UFO, it always just disappears.

Comment: Can anyone provide a video or a screenshot of the UFO? I always thought that the aliens or UFOs in GTA: San Andreas were false rumors, or is just added by mods.